# How to show flyout on itemclick in listview nested in a grouped listview

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simulated dynamic grid, using a list of lists. The parent listview is a grouped listview. It's items are horizontal stacked lists.

On the innermost cells I need to show a flyout or popup. I tried using Flyouts on SelectionChanged and ItemClicked events of the child list's items - the flyouts simply do not show. To show a popup I would need coordinates - there's no way to get them using the SelectionChanged and ItemClick events.

If I try to get the clicked cell's coordinates, only the vertical coordinate value get's the exact value, for the horizontal offset I get a static value, probably the horizontal offset of the parent list.

What could I do to display a flyout / popup when I click on a cell in the child lists?

This is the Xaml:

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ResultsPanelScrollViewer"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">             
        <utils:AlternatingRowListView x:Name="ResultsPanel"
            Margin="0"
            EvenRowBackground="{StaticResource LabResultsListItemBackground}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResultsPanelListViewItemStyle}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding LabResultsDetailsCollection.View,Mode=OneWay}"
            OddRowBackground="{StaticResource ListViewItemBackground}"
            RelativePanel.RightOf="CategoriesPanel" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource 
            LabResultsListViewGroupStyle}" 
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ValuesListHeaderTemplate}" />
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <ListView Margin="0"
                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ValuesItemTemplate}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding LabResults}"
                       Padding="0"
                       IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                       ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
                       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Padding="0" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                       <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                          <Flyout>
                              <TextBlock Text="sdfasd"/>
                          </Flyout>
                       </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                     </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </utils:AlternatingRowListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
        private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = sender as ListView;    
            var gt = x.TransformToVisual(this);
            var screenPoint = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));    
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
        }

        private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = sender;    
            var gt = ((ListView)e.OriginalSource).TransformToVisual(this);
            var screenPoint = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
                  <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                      <Flyout>
                          <TextBlock Text="sdfasd"/>
                      </Flyout>
                   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

should be attached in your ValuesItemTemplate itemtemplate not in the listview